# Should this be else if statement?

Tags: powershell

Working on a script for my team that runs a status check on a list of url's.  Completely bogus url's are still comming back 200.  Should i use a else if?

```
   #Place URL list file in the below path
   $sites = Get-Content -Path .\customer_sites.txt

   foreach ($site in $sites){
   $status = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $site -UseDefaultCredentials -AllowUnencryptedAuthentication - 
   ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).statuscode
   switch ($status) {
    200 { 
        Write-Host "Status code $status for site $site ALL GOOD" -ForegroundColor Green
        # further action/code specific to code 200 here 
    }
    401 { 
        Write-Host "Status code $status for site $site SERVER IS UP BUT NO ACCESS" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        # further action/code specific to code 404 here  
    }
    default { 
        Write-Host "Status code $status for site $site ITS DEAD, GO LOOK" -ForegroundColor Red
        # further action/code specific to 'other' here 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are asking for opinion on data that we don't have. Please define completely bogus url by providing some examples.

Comment: I tested your script with a made up site name and it ended up in the default branch saying the site is dead. Can you please retry your script and then post some actual content of that file that does in fact produce such a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think that by using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, the status variable keeps its old value and therefore returns "ALL GOOD".

a better way is to put the test inside a `try..catch` block.

Something like

```
$sites = Get-Content -Path .\customer_sites.txt

foreach ($site in $sites) {
    try{
        $response  = Invoke-WebRequest $site -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -Method Head -ErrorAction Stop
        $status = [int]$response.StatusCode
    }
    catch {
        $status = [int]$_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
    }
    switch ($status) {
        {$_ -ge 100 -and $_ -lt 300}  { 
            Write-Host "Status code $status for site $site ALL GOOD" -ForegroundColor Green
            break
        }
        {$_ -ge 300 -and $_ -lt 400}  { 
            Write-Host "$site is redirected. Statuscode: $status" -ForegroundColor Green
            break
        }
        {$_ -ge 400 -and $_ -lt 500}  { 
            Write-Host "Status code $status for site $site SERVER IS UP BUT NO ACCESS" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            break
        }
        {$_ -ge 500 -and $_ -lt 600}  { 
            Write-Host "Status code $status for site $site ITS DEAD, GO LOOK" -ForegroundColor Red
            break
        }
        default { Write-Host "$site returned an unhandled status code. Statuscode: $status, GO LOOK" -ForegroundColor Red}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  I need to read up on switch statements, I've very new to this.  With the above script though, 401 and 404 are kicking back the following.

Comment: @YukaputzMike I have edited the answer. Now in case of error, the status is read from the Exception.Response.