# Powershell 5.0 Invoke-Restmethod Sucess Statuscode

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-5.0

I want to get the Satuscode when the HTTP returns code 200, i know there is way to use try , Catch but thats to catch error StatusCode, what is the way to catch the sucessfull status code 200 using Invoke-Restmethod in Powershell 5.1 ?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why did you write version 5.0 in the title, 5.1 in the question and added tag `powershell-2.0` ?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65653074/9898643) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62453104/9898643) ?

Comment: $status = [int]$response.StatusCode only work for powershell7.0 and above , but it worked if i change it to Invoke-Webrequest instead of Restmethod